# Force game through Fiddler proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, tunnel

I would like to view (perhaps fiddle with, later on) traffic from a game on my computer, using Fiddler (or perhaps you can suggest an alternative). The game ignores the Internet Explorer proxy settings and creates a direct connection. Please read the things I've tried:

1. Using ProxyCap program to force the game's executable to go through the Fiddler proxy, setting the proxy with HTTPS in ProxyCap. In this case, ProxyCap successfully routes the game through the Fiddler proxy, however the connection to the game fails and I see only these types of sessions in Fiddler:

Raw Request:

> CONNECT //game-related-address//://game-related-port// HTTP/1.0
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Host: //same-game-related-address//://same-game-related-port//
>
> A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
>
> Version: 3.0 (SSL/3.0)
>
> Random: 95 49 02 8C 99 D7 AE 22 F4 F6 97 B4 26 9E 65 58 C2 81 36 CD 1B 36 34 3E A0 CA BF 
>   16 3C A1 0C CD
>
> SessionID: empty
>
> Extensions: 
>     none
>
> Ciphers: 
>       [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>       [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
>       [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
>       [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
>
> Compression: 
>       [00]    NO_COMPRESSION

Raw Response:

> HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
>
> FiddlerGateway: Direct
>
> StartTime: 22:23:07.649
>
> Connection: close

2. (This is two, dunno why the formatting turns it into a 1) Using Putty and doing the following (I admit I do not really understand SSH tunneling): Setting Putty's destination host 127.0.0.1 and port Fiddler's port. Under tunnels setting, setting a dynamic source port 8080. Under proxycap, changing to proxy to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 with SSH (also tried the two SOCKS options). Then running the putty tunnel, running proxycap, and running the game. When I try to connect within the game, the connection fails, proxycap throws some winsock error, and after a while putty throws an error as well.

Any information is appreciated (please read what I have tried before linking me to a duplicate question).

Comment: Fiddler is a HTTP debugger. Your game probably doesn't use HTTP, but it's own dedicated protocol. Try Wireshark.

Comment: I haven't ever used Wireshark. What filter would you suggest I try for capturing the game's packets. It does not have a constant IP address, and I don't know which ports it uses.

Comment: I've managed to filter out the relevant packets in Wireshark. But is there some way to make sense of the data? It's a TCP packet. Fiddler allows me to decrypt sessions (I guess because it's HTTPS). Can I not do something of the sort here?